# Gitlab PUSH syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, gitlab

I've installed Gitlab 5, all ran smoothly until I attempted to make a test PUSH. The error is:

```
remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:33:in `eval_gemfile': Gemfile syntax error: (Bundler::GemfileError)        
remote: /home/git/gitlab/Gemfile:14: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end        
remote: gem "mysql2", group: :mysql        
remote:                     ^
```

I searched all over the internet (well, kind of), but mostly the answer is about using a lower version of ruby (1.8.7). Which is not the case here, as you can see, I'm using 2.0.0-p0.

I'm attaching the Gemfile as well, which is from Gitlab source code, so I reckon there's nothing wrong with it. Just in case:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

def darwin_only(require_as)
  RUBY_PLATFORM.include?('darwin') && require_as
end

def linux_only(require_as)
  RUBY_PLATFORM.include?('linux') && require_as
end

gem "rails", "3.2.13"

# Supported DBs
gem "mysql2", group: :mysql
gem "pg", group: :postgres

# Auth
gem "devise"
gem 'omniauth', "~> 1.1.3"
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-github'

# Extracting information from a git repository
# Since gollum requires grit we cannot use gitlab-grit gem name any more. Use grit instead
gem "grit", '~> 2.5.0', git: 'https://github.com/gitlabhq/grit.git', ref: '42297cdcee16284d2e4eff23d41377f52fc28b9d'
gem 'grit_ext', '~> 0.8.1'

# Ruby/Rack Git Smart-HTTP Server Handler
gem 'gitlab-grack', '~> 1.0.0', require: 'grack'

# LDAP Auth
gem 'gitlab_omniauth-ldap', '1.0.2', require: "omniauth-ldap"

# Syntax highlighter
gem "gitlab-pygments.rb", '~> 0.3.2', require: 'pygments.rb'

# Language detection
gem "github-linguist", "~> 2.3.4" , require: "linguist"

# API
gem "grape", "~> 0.3.1"
gem "grape-entity", "~> 0.2.0"

# Format dates and times
# based on human-friendly examples
gem "stamp"

# Enumeration fields
gem 'enumerize'

# Pagination
gem "kaminari", "~> 0.14.1"

# HAML
gem "haml-rails"

# Files attachments
gem "carrierwave"

# Authorization
gem "six"

# Seed data
gem "seed-fu"

# Markdown to HTML
gem "redcarpet",     "~> 2.2.2"
gem "github-markup", "~> 0.7.4", require: 'github/markup'

# Servers
gem "puma", '~> 2.0.0.b7'

# State machine
gem "state_machine"

# Issue tags
gem "acts-as-taggable-on", "2.3.3"

# Background jobs
gem 'slim'
gem 'sinatra', require: nil
gem 'sidekiq'

# HTTP requests
gem "httparty"

# Colored output to console
gem "colored"

# GitLab settings
gem 'settingslogic'

# Git Wiki
gem "gollum-lib", "~> 1.0.0"

# Misc
gem "foreman"

# Cache
gem "redis-rails"

group :assets do
  gem "sass-rails",   "~> 3.2.5"
  gem "coffee-rails", "~> 3.2.2"
  gem "uglifier",     "~> 1.3.0"
  gem "therubyracer"

  gem 'chosen-rails',     "0.9.8"
  gem 'select2-rails'
  gem 'jquery-atwho-rails', "0.1.7"
  gem "jquery-rails",     "2.1.3"
  gem "jquery-ui-rails",  "2.0.2"
  gem "modernizr",        "2.6.2"
  gem "raphael-rails",    git: "https://github.com/gitlabhq/raphael-rails.git"
  gem 'bootstrap-sass',   "2.2.1.1"
  gem "font-awesome-sass-rails", "~> 3.0.0"
  gem "gemoji", "~> 1.2.1", require: 'emoji/railtie'
  gem "gon"
end

group :development do
  gem "annotate", git: "https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.git"
  gem "letter_opener"
  gem 'quiet_assets', '~> 1.0.1'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
  # Better errors handler
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'

  gem 'rails_best_practices'

  # Docs generator
  gem "sdoc"

  # thin instead webrick
  gem 'thin'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'coveralls', require: false
  gem 'rails-dev-tweaks'
  gem 'spinach-rails'
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "pry"
  gem "awesome_print"
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem "launchy"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'

  # Generate Fake data
  gem "ffaker"

  # Guard
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-spinach'

  # Notification
  gem 'rb-fsevent', require: darwin_only('rb-fsevent')
  gem 'growl',      require: darwin_only('growl')
  gem 'rb-inotify', require: linux_only('rb-inotify')

  # PhantomJS driver for Capybara
  gem 'poltergeist', git: 'https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist.git', ref: '9645b52009e258921b860d3b7601d00008b22c45'

  gem 'spork', '~> 1.0rc'
end

group :test do
  gem "simplecov", require: false
  gem "shoulda-matchers", "1.3.0"
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem "webmock"
  gem 'test_after_commit'
end

group :production do
  gem "gitlab_meta", '5.0'
end
```

Could anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you somehow got multiple ruby versions running ? What do `ruby -v` and `which bundle`  return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved this. Somehow Gitlab gems (bundles?) still used the system ruby (1.8.7). I had to `yum remove` it, and things work now.

Comment: Looks great. +1. I would be interested to know if your gitlab works with ruby2.0, or if, as in my answer, 1.9.3 is still necessary.

Comment: 2.0 works fine. I encountered some problems with 1.9.3, but I guess that was just me.

Comment: That was the answer dead on.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Issue 3080](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3080) and in the [GitLab requirement section](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq#requirements):

> ruby 1.9.3

I would try first switching to ruby1.9.3 (certainly not 1.8.x).

Comment: Hmm. Let me try switching.

Comment: I've switched to 1.9.3, and even set `rvm --default 1.9.3`. However, after `service gitlab restart` and attempting to PUSH, the exact error appears. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Edit: By "exact" I meant "exact": it still say ruby 2.0.0:

    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb

Comment: @AnP "the exact error" meaning still referring to a ruby2.0? (as in `gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.5`?)

Comment: @AnP ok, so you need to "clean" that ruby2.0, and check your environment variables for any reference to ruby2.0 path.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "clean?" Thanks.

Comment: @AnP delete the files from ruby2.0, make sure it is un-installed.

Comment: Is it safe for me to do so? I have a redmine instance using 2.0.0.

Comment: @AnP In that case, no. I am use to rely on only local installation, never using system path (but that is because I compile Everything: https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything). In your case, I suspect environment variable, or at least the `$PATH` should be examined closely in order to make sure that your Gitlab instance is using the right Ruby.

Comment: This is my `$PATH`: `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin`

Apparently there's no 1.9.3 there, I wonder why. And how should I fix that?

Comment: @AnP So it does make sense that gitlab is still using ruby2.0, doesn't it? Could you, in a special launching script, change that `PATH`?

Comment: @AnP or at least, as in http://www.rubyinside.com/rvm-ruby-version-manager-2347.html, typing  **rvm use `1.9.3`**

Comment: I did `rvm use 1.9.3`, as in my second comment in this thread. It didn't work.

Comment: @AnP sorry, I missed that part. I am afraid that is my limit in term of using ruby, so back to try and modifying the PATH, then ;)

Comment: This is the latest error: `remote: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:33:in `eval_gemfile': Gemfile syntax error: (Bundler::GemfileError)        
remote: /home/git/gitlab/Gemfile:14: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end        
remote: gem "mysql2", group: :mysql` Now I suspect that the error is not from the ruby version itself, but some gem (Bundle?) was installed by the system 1.8.7 ruby, as it this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588741/trouble-installing-gitlab-5-0-i-cant-finish-the-installation. How should I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

After spending around 3 hours on exactly same problem, solution was as given by : An Phan

Do 
$ rpm -qa | grep -i ruby

It will give you like ruby.1.8..*****

DO 
 yum erase ruby.1.8..*****

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
group :mysql do 
  gem "mysql2"
end

group :postgres do 
  gem "pg"
end
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, I've tried the code change, and other errors happen elsewhere. Actually I don't think this is the fix to the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Remove completely the folder `vendor/bundle` and rerun the deployment command while using 1.9.3 with rvm.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with gitlab when it was trying to merge for me.
When git runs a hook, it modifies the environment path. On my machine it adds /usr/libexec/git-core and /usr/bin to the beginning of the path.

So the gitlab-shell update hook shebang of `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` runs, it will always pickup system ruby always in /usr/bin, instead of looking into the rvm path (something like /home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin).

Either removing system ruby or modifying the shebang to run the rvm ruby directly should work.