# Gitlab PUSH Gemfile syntax error: (Bundler::GemfileError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubygems, gitlab

Following on from this previously asked question: 
[Gitlab PUSH syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411020/gitlab-push-syntax-error-unexpected-expecting-end)

I've worked with my current set up for about one and half years. Didn't upgrade anything recently, but I suddenly saw this error when trying to PUSH:

```
remote: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler  /dsl.rb:33:in `eval_gemfile': Gemfile syntax error: (Bundler::GemfileError)
remote: /home/git/gitlab/Gemfile:14: syntax error, unexpected ':',   expecting $end
remote: gem "mysql2", group: :mysql
remote:                     ^
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib  /bundler/dsl.rb:9:in `evaluate'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:19:in `build'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib /bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib /bundler/setup.rb:17
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/develop
```

I've installed rvm and the latest ruby

```
ruby --version
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

The solution user 'An Phan' had to this was to manually remove the system version of ruby. As I am using a Mac and know that other applications can rely on this, I was hoping to find another way to resolve this issue.

Thanks!

EDIT: The server is managed by another team in my company and all my colleagues also use it. They have no issues pushing.

Comment: The issue is not on your local Mac but on the server. That's what the other question is about too: you have to ensure that the Ruby versions on the server are up-to-date. In your case, it seems to be the exact same issue as the linked question, namely that the server attempts to use an old Ruby version to verify the `Gemfile`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! However the server I'm using is a shared work server, and continues to work for all of my colleagues. If it doesn't have anything to do with my local setup, do you know why would it fail only for me?